# Replacing word in complex string in js

Tags: javascript

I have below string:

```
$("#trip-to").after(
            '<div class="disambi">' + '<div class="disambiguation-indicator"></div>' + '<div class="disambiguation-inner-wrapper">' + ' <p><strong> &ldquo;'+query+ '&rdquo;.</strong></p>' + ' <p><strong>Did you mean to...</strong></p>' + '<ul>' + suggest + '</ul>' + (count >= 14 ? ' <p><a class="js-disambiguation-show-more" data-parent="to">Show more locations...</a></p>' : '') + '</div>' + '</div>');
        resultQuery = query;
```

I want to replace `"to"` in above with `"from"` on a condition.
I tried replace function but it it not giving proper output....
may be because of so many `"` and `'`

Any other thing i missed out?

Comment: there are about 3 **to**'s which ones you want changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create your output string as a variable:

```
var outputStr = '<div class="disambi">' + '<div class="disambiguation-indicator"></div>' + '<div class="disambiguation-inner-wrapper">' + ' <p><strong> &ldquo;'+query+ '&rdquo;.</strong></p>' + ' <p><strong>Did you mean to...</strong></p>' + '<ul>' + suggest + '</ul>' + (count >= 14 ? ' <p><a class="js-disambiguation-show-more" data-parent="to">Show more locations...</a></p>' : '') + '</div>' + '</div>');
```

And then do your *replace* on the variable ?

Then you can simply dump the modified string where you want it to go:

```
$("#trip-to").after(outputStr);
```